# How do I key in an action of a edit text box in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Based on the following main.xml code (snippet below), how do I get the java code in the class to save the data that the user types in??

```
<TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="year of car" />
            <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/myeditfield"
                      android:layout_width="100px"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview1_1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="make of car" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/myeditfield"
                android:layout_width="200px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview1_2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="model of car" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/myeditfield"
                android:layout_width="200px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1_2);
String txt =tv.getText().toString();
```

Comment: in you .java file which was extending the Activity

Comment: I get a warning that variable txt is never used.  Also, when I hit enter on the text field, it inserts another line and the cursor doesn't move to the next field.  Any clues here??

Comment: in your xml layout add this in your text view android:singleline="true"

Comment: I tried that and my project is telling me that there is an error when I have than line in there.

Comment: i found my error...but hitting enter still gives multiple lines.